# Find which git commit remove some file content

Tags: git

I would like to identify all the commits that removed a specified string from any file of the repository.

Here is the case for which I need this : I have a java method called someMethod
I know this method was called in the past but it is not anymore (somebody removed the code). I don't know from which file it was called.

So this is my question : Is it possible to find which commit removed this method call. More generally, is it possible to find the commits that removed the string "someMethod" from any file?
Manually, I would generate unified diff for each commit and look if someMethod appears in the diff.

Is there an automatic process to do it?

Comment: I would definitely do this the manual way: `git log --all -p | less` and search for "someMethod" interactively within `less`.

Comment: Thank you. Using this command but with grep instead of less is good for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely do this the manual way: `git log --all -p | less` and search for "someMethod" interactively within `less`.

Using grep on the output is also a possibility, but then you have to work harder to find which commit the changes were made in.

Comment: I also added "commit" to grep so commits are displayed too :  git log --all -p | less | grep "someMethod\|commit"

Comment: Simple and effective solution, I should have thought of it. :)